# mongoDB Query-eliminate repeating results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection which looks like this :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("558c108b209c022c947b0055"),
"term" : "aero storm tour",
"year" : "2015",
"month" : "06",
"day" : "01",
"hour" : "17",
"dayofyear" : "184",
"weekofyear" : 26,
"productcount" : 2,
"count" : 1
}


{
"_id" : ObjectId("558c108b209c022c947b0056"),
"term" : "aero storm tour",
"year" : "2015",
"month" : "06",
"day" : "01",
"hour" : "17",
"dayofyear" : "184",
"weekofyear" : 26,
"productcount" : 2,
"count" : 2
}


{
"_id" : ObjectId("558c108b209c022c947b0026"),
"term" : "aero",
"year" : "2015",
"month" : "06",
"day" : "01",
"hour" : "17",
"dayofyear" : "184",
"weekofyear" : 26,
"productcount" : 23,
"count" : 2
}


{
"_id" : ObjectId("558c108b209c022c947b0022"),
"term" : "aero",
"year" : "2015",
"month" : "06",
"day" : "01",
"hour" : "17",
"dayofyear" : "184",
"weekofyear" : 26,
"productcount" : 23,
"count" : 12
}


{
"_id" : ObjectId("558c108b209c022c947b0032"),
"term" : "aero",
"year" : "2015",
"month" : "07",
"day" : "01",
"hour" : "17",
"dayofyear" : "184",
"weekofyear" : 26,
"productcount" : 23,
"count" : 12
}


{
"_id" : ObjectId("5348c108b09c022c947b0055"),
"term" : "aero storm tour",
"year" : "2015",
"month" : "06",
"day" : "01",
"hour" : "17",
"dayofyear" : "170",
"weekofyear" : 26,
"productcount" : 235,
"count" : 1
}


{
"_id" : ObjectId("658c108b209c022c947b0055"),
"term" : "aero storm tour",
"year" : "2015",
"month" : "06",
"day" : "01",
"hour" : "17",
"dayofyear" : "173",
"weekofyear" : 26,
"productcount" : 235,
"count" : 1
}


{
"_id" : ObjectId("558c108b209c022c947a0055"),
"term" : "aero storm tour",
"year" : "2015",
"month" : "06",
"day" : "01",
"hour" : "17",
"dayofyear" : "164",
"weekofyear" : 26,
"productcount" : 235,
"count" : 1
}
```

I need to find the **term** where **productcount** is less than equals to 2 on a particular **year** , **month** and **day** .

**My query** :

```
db.tq.find( 
            { year : "2015" , month : "06" , day : "01" ,productcount: { $lte: 2 } } ,
            { _id: 0, term: 1, productcount: 1 }

          )
```

**Output** :

```
{
"term" : "aero storm tour",
"productcount" : 2
}
{
"term" : "aero storm tour",
"productcount" : 2
}
```

It returns the correct result but I want to avoid repetitive results by using something like distinct or similar.

**Expected output:**

```
{
"term" : "aero storm tour",
"productcount" : 2
}
```

How to achieve that ?

Comment: No there is a productcount field in the documents.

{
"_id" : ObjectId("558c108b209c022c947b0056"),
"term" : "aero storm tour",
"year" : "2015",
"month" : "06",
"day" : "01",
"hour" : "17",
"dayofyear" : "184",
"weekofyear" : 26,
`"productcount" : 2`,
"count" : 2
}

Comment: do you want result with highest `productcount` if there are two or more same documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `find` query is not working because for the date you are matching, there are two documents in your collection. That is why it is giving you two documents as a result.

You can work add `limit` to find query to get only one result like following-

```js
db.collection.find({
    year: "2015",
    month: "06",
    day: "01",
    productcount: {
        $lte: 2
    }
    }, {
    _id: 0,
    term: 1,
    productcount: 1
    }
).limit(1)
```

**Otherwise**

You can use [mongo aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) to get expected result as shown as following:

```js
db.collection.aggregate({
    $match: {
    productcount: {
        $lte: 2
    },
    year: "2015",
    month: "06",
    day: "01"
    }
}, {
    $group: {
    _id: "$term",
    "term": {
        $first: "$term"
    },
    "productcount": {
        $first: "$productcount" //u can add $max:"$productcount" to get productcount with max value instead of $first: "$productcount"
    }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
    "term": 1,
    "productcount": 1,
    "_id": 0
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks man. The aggregate one suits my requirment because there will many different terms.I am testing it on a smaller data set.

Comment: Thanks for max productcount suggestion.Will add it if requirments changes.

Comment: @user-4870385 . I also added comment if you want to maximum productcount then u can use  `$max:"$productcount"` instead of `$first: "$productcount"`